# FileStream и расширение длины файла

Tags: c#, .net, файлы

Если открывается пустой файл, который не содержит данных, т.е. новый файл, возможно ли позиционирование при помощи `Seek`, т.е. изменение его длины (размера)?

Причины по которым интересуюсь, делаю частичное скачивание, т.е. контент делится на `HttpPart`, и качается его определенная часть. А точнее, части могут качаться абсолютно в произвольном порядке *(такие уж они `Task`'и)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала создай файл нужного размера:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create))
  fs.SetLength(123456789);
```

а потом в нём позиционируйся.

Comment: Хм, а если вызывать `SetLength` в каждой задаче, если длина от конца меньше необходимой? будет нормально?

Comment: @LLENN, а зачем? Резервируй один раз целиком и всё.

Comment: Просто кол-во частей зависит от размера файла, а размер одного буфера 4 МБ, пересчитывать размер не выгодно. Хотя есть идея брать длину от последнего парта контента. Попробую так...

Comment: @LLENN, заголовок `content-length`. Он необязателен, но раз уж поддерживается `range`, то вероятно и он будет.